# Repeat while loop if input is a specific string

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I just created a small game and I want to repeat it if the user wants to. i created an input and after words tried to set the guess_count variable back to 0, so i thought it will trigger the while loop again.

```
secret_number = 8
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = int(input("Guess the number: "))
    guess_count += 1
    if guess == secret_number:
        print("You won!")
        break
else:
    print("Sorry, you failed!")
    try_again = input("Try again? ")
    if try_again == "yes":
        guess_count = 0
```

Comment: Put it all into a function. Then call the function as many times as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `guess_count` back to `0` in the `else` block will not trigger the loop again. This is because the `else` block is executed after the loop has exited. You might want to move the logic to restart the loop into the loop itself. eg.

```py
secret_number = 8
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
while True:
    if guess_count >= guess_limit:
        print("Sorry, you failed!")
        try_again = input("Try again? ")
        if try_again == "yes":
            guess_count = 0
            continue
        else:
            break
    else:
        guess = int(input("Guess the number: "))
        guess_count += 1
        if guess == secret_number:
            print("You won!")
            break
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I didnt think of it that way! Really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
playing = True

secret_number = 8

while playing:
    guess_count = 0
    guess_limit = 3

while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = int(input("Guess the number: "))
    guess_count += 1
    if guess == secret_number:
        print("You won!")
        break
else:
    print("Sorry, you failed!")
try_again = input("Try again? (yes/no) ")
if try_again == "no":
    playing = False
```